# ¿Cómo relacionar estas tablas?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo tres tablas:

- Users
- Profiles
- Ads

Estoy listando todos los anuncios que se encuentren publicados, me los muestra... Pero requiero mostrar la foto del perfil junto al anuncio, pero la collección no me trae la información del perfil y el problema debe estar en la relación.

Mi tabla users en la migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('city_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('phone')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Mi tabla Profiles en la migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('profession_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('profession_id')->references('id')->on('professions');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Mi tabla Ads en la migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('status')->default('DRAFT');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Las tengo relacionadas de la siguiente manera:

Model User:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
}

public function ads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
}
```

Model Profile:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
} 

public function profession()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profession::class);
}
```

Model ads

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
} 

public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
}
```

Mi consulta en el controlador:

```
public function index()
{

    $ads = Ad::with('user.profile')
               ->whereStatus('PUBLISHED')
               ->orderBy('ads.id', 'DESC')
               ->paginate(12);

               dd($ads);

    return  view('web/users/listing', compact('ads'));

}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: En el modelo User, la relación profile() debería ser hasOne, ya que en el Modelo Profile la relación user() es belongsTo, y la llave foránea está en Profile.

Comment: Okey, muchas gracias

Comment: No, aún no funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué versión exacta de Laravel es?

Comment: La versión es: 6.12.0

Comment: Prueba con esta consulta: `Ad::with([ 'user' => function ($query) { $query->with('profile'); } ]) ->whereStatus('PUBLISHED') ->orderBy('id', 'desc') ->get();`

Comment: Tampoco, no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Creería que es una relación uno a uno entre el usuario y el perfil, por lo cual el error que creo que estás cometiendo es que no estás definiendo correctamente la relación desde el modelo User:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Shaz, pero no solucionó el problema

Comment: Voy a replicar completamente el código que nos compartes y te contaré.

Comment: La respuesta es correcta y el problema si está como defines las relaciones

Comment: La colección aún muestra "profile" => null

Comment: Me gustaría saber el motivo del -1 cuando de las dos respuestas está es la única correcta

Comment: Supongo que a alguien no le caigo bien, porque no veo otro motivo. Sería bueno que lo escribieran en un comentario.

Comment: También me parece correcta la respuesta. @Joseph, estás seguro que en la base de datos tienes los datos correspondientes? Podrías probar si `User::with('profile')->get()` te devuelve los datos de Profile para cada User?

Comment: Sí, me devuelve los datos de profile User::with('profile')->get()

Comment: La versión 6.12.0, no funcionó la consulta que me diste

Answer (score 0):

Según como veo tu migración entiendo que un Usuario puede tener 1 o mas Perfiles (asumiré que es 1:1), como también 1 o más Anuncios (1:N). Asumiendo estas cosas y siguiendo la [DOCUMENTACIÓN](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) las relaciones entre los modelos deberían quedar de esta forma:

Modelo User:

```
//Retorna el perfil del usuario
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_id');
}

//Retorna los anuncios del usuario
public function ads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ad', 'user_id');
}
```

Modelo Profile:

```
//Retorna al usuario del perfil
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Modelo Ads:

```
//Retorna al usuario del anuncio
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Si te das cuenta yo utilizo 2 parámetros para las relaciones, el primero indica el modelo con el cual se relacionará la instancia y el segundo la clave foranea. No es obligatorio pero yo lo suelo colocar.
Si tu propósito es mostrar los anuncios con el usuario y su perfil lo podemos hacer muy simplemente gracias a Eloquent de esta forma:

Use App\Ad;

```
$anuncios = Ad::all();  //Todos los anuncios

foreach($anuncios as $anuncio) {

    //Titulo y descipcion del Anuncio
    //dd($anuncio->title);
    //dd($anuncio->description);

    //Retorna al usuario dueño del anuncio
    //dd($anuncio->user);

    //Retorna el perfil del usuario dueño del anuncio
    //dd($anuncio->user->profile)

    //Retorna la foto del perfil
    //dd($anuncio->user->profile->photo)
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Coméntame como te va! saludos.

Comment: La respuesta me parece en principio igual a la que ya dio Shaz y segundo si vas a mostrar datos de una relación es una mala idea de rendimiento usar all y en vez de eso se debería hacer uso de eager loading, ya que como está ahorita las relaciones quedan sin uso y aplicacion

Comment: Es una relación 1:1 User-Profile, no... Intenté con tu código y aún no se resuelve.

Comment: Eso debería funcionar amigo, intenta ver si todos tus modelos están correctamente relacionados con sus tablas y atributos respectivamente, o también puedes hacer pruebas utilizando Tinker para ver dónde está el problema. Te deseo éxito.